# In eclipse how to save logcat error message

Tags: android, eclipse

In eclipse how can I save logcat error message..?
it is possible to save one message..
How can I save totall message..?

Answer (score 1):

Select one (or more) messages and click "Export Selected Items to Text File ..." button (fourth button from the right in the logcat view)

Answer (score 0):

Select the lines you want to export and then click this button:

[image]